Key: WHAT IS MAN? connections between Book of Job & Psalms?
The question 'What is man?" occurs only 4 times in the Hebrew Masoretic Text, twice in the Book of Job & twice in Psalms.  There is an obvious thematic connection between the 2 sets of references that is highlighted in the table below.  Besides the obvious thematic connection, are there other connections & what is the significance of these connections?
For example, it was noted in the Answer to the Question "What is the significance of Adam & Son of man in Psalm 8 compared to Man & Son of Adam in Psalm 144?" that the Book of Job may be a source for the question in Psalm 144.

[!Thematic Connection]

Question: Besides the obvious thematic connection, are there other connections & what is the significance of these connections?
